# Bootstrap navigation pills have extra white space between them

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is a simple bootstrap code I am trying, where the **floated block elements** have extra space between them. How do I remove it, and why is it there ?

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li style="width: 40%; background: #8ac1dc;" class="active">
    <a href="#ap-about" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">About</a>
  </li>
  <li style="width: 40%; background: #ff6666">
    <a href="#ap-personal" data-toggle="tab">Account</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dod1wrd7/2/)

Comment: if you asking abt space beetween anchor text and nav then you can remove padding from left for anchor tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove margin

**CSS**

```
.nav-pills>li+li{
    margin:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
 <ul class="nav nav-pills">
   <li style="width: 40%; background: #8ac1dc;" class="active">
    <a href="#ap-about" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true" style="border-radius: 0;">About</a>
  </li>
 <!--  -->
 <li style="width: 40%; background: #ff6666;margin:0">
  <a href="#ap-personal" data-toggle="tab" style="border-radius: 0;">Account</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `bootstrap.css` file on line `4093` and edit 2px to 0

```
.nav-pills > li + li {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: But by doing this it will solve his problem in every page. He doesn't need to do same work repeatedly.

Comment: if required in multiple pages then he can add in custom style file with important mark.

Answer (score 1):

```
Update the bootstrap.css margin-left from 2px to 0px 
.nav-pills > li + li {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your custom class in ul like `my-nav-pills`

and add css like below

```
.my-nav-pills li{
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

it is batter to overwrite the bootstrap class and dont change the css of default bootstrap class.